# assigning variables in the View in ASP MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Actually I'm very new to ASP.NET MVC and I need your help.

Here I have some Create Method that takes an argument from the URL to use it as id:

in 'vote' controller :

```
    public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        Meeting meeting = db.Meetings.Find(id); // get the object
        ViewBag.meetingID = meeting.meetingID;  // get its id and assign it to a ViewBag

        return View();
    }
```

and I would like to do something like :

```
vote.meetingID = @ViewBag.meetingID
```

in the model so that is directly assgin this property without excplicitely typing it from the HTML view (I mean @Html.EditorFor(model=>meetingID) )

Comment: What's wrong with view models? http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/three-reasons-to-why-you-should-use-view-models/

Answer (score 0):

The question is not that clear, but try this.

You could pass the entire model to the view.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{ 
    Meeting meeting = db.Meetings.Find(id); // get the object 
    ViewData["myMeeting"] = meeting;

    return View(); 
}
```

To use in the view you can declare it as a variable at the top of the view:

Declare:

```
@
{
    var meetingData = ViewData["myMeeting"] as Meeting;
}
```

Usage:

```
<div>
    @meetingData.meetingID
</div>
```